# How could I save this text in a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to save very large text in a variable (SPACE INVADERS), How can I save that type of text in a variable? . I'm learning c # I need help please.

Code: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
namespace SpaceInvaders2017
{
    class Program
    {
        struct AtribEnemigos {
            public string simbolo;
            public ConsoleColor color;
            public bool visible;
            public int posColInicial;
            public int posFilaInicial;
            public float x, y;

        }
        static int nombre;
        static AtribEnemigos Texto;
        public static void MenuJuego(){     
            Console.Clear();
            MoverNombreJuego();
        }
        public static void MoverNombreJuego()
        {
            Texto.color = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
            Texto.posColInicial = 0;
            Texto.posFilaInicial = 0;
            Texto.x = Texto.posColInicial;
            Texto.y = Texto.posFilaInicial;
 //Error here------------------------
            Texto.simbolo = { "▄▀▀ █▀▄ ▄▀▄ ▄▀▀ █▀▀ . ▀█▀ █▄░█ █░░░█ ▄▀▄ █▀▄ █▀▀ █▀▄ ▄▀▀ ",
                              "░▀▄ █▀░ █▄█ █░░ █▀▀ . ░█░ █▀██ ░█░█░ █▄█ █░█  █▀▀ █▀▄ ░▀▄ ",
                              "▀▀░ ▀░░ ▀░▀ ░▀▀ ▀▀▀ . ▀▀▀ ▀░░▀ ░░▀░░ ▀░▀ ▀▀░ ▀▀▀ ▀░▀ ▀▀░"};
        }

        public static void PausaFotograma()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(40);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MenuJuego();
            //Console.ReadKey();
            PausaFotograma();
        }
    }
}
```

[Image with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9gQS.png)

Comment: you mean multi-line text? put an @ before the string double quote opening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **@** for multi-line string:

```
        Texto.simbolo = 
            @"▄▀▀ █▀▄ ▄▀▄ ▄▀▀ █▀▀ . ▀█▀ █▄░█ █░░░█ ▄▀▄ █▀▄ █▀▀ █▀▄ ▄▀▀ 
░▀▄ █▀░ █▄█ █░░ █▀▀ . ░█░ █▀██ ░█░█░ █▄█ █░█  █▀▀ █▀▄ ░▀▄ 
▀▀░ ▀░░ ▀░▀ ░▀▀ ▀▀▀ . ▀▀▀ ▀░░▀ ░░▀░░ ▀░▀ ▀▀░ ▀▀▀ ▀░▀ ▀▀░";
```

or join strings with + operator and add new lines explicitly:

```
Texto.simbolo =
    "▄▀▀ █▀▄ ▄▀▄ ▄▀▀ █▀▀ . ▀█▀ █▄░█ █░░░█ ▄▀▄ █▀▄ █▀▀ █▀▄ ▄▀▀ " + Environment.NewLine +
    "░▀▄ █▀░ █▄█ █░░ █▀▀ . ░█░ █▀██ ░█░█░ █▄█ █░█  █▀▀ █▀▄ ░▀▄ " + Environment.NewLine +
    "▀▀░ ▀░░ ▀░▀ ░▀▀ ▀▀▀ . ▀▀▀ ▀░░▀ ░░▀░░ ▀░▀ ▀▀░ ▀▀▀ ▀░▀ ▀▀░";
```

Comment: Thanks, I run into the two options.

Comment: @yvanGarcia You didnt "run into" anything.  People took the time shared their expertise with you.  Be sure to click the checkmark on the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the project resources in order to store texts.

- Right click the project in the Solution Explorer and click "Properties".
- Select the tab "Resources".
- In the strings section enter a name for the resource and a value. (Increase the row height and column width for large texts).
- Close the project properties.

[image]

Now you can write:

```
Texto.simbolo = Properties.Resources.SpaceInvadersTitle;
```

You will see that Visual Studio lists `SpaceInvadersTitle` in intellisense.

Comment: Very interesting, do you have to specify the project name -`myProjectName.Properties.Resources.SpaceInvadersTitle`, or you can use it without. I was reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Great, works well and keeps the code cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: @StanleyS: The `Properties` word is part of the namespace. If you are already in the  `myProjectName`, you can drop it. You could also add a `using myProjectName.Properties;` instead and then simply write `Resources.SpaceInvadersTitle`, where `Resources` is a class with static properties for all the resources.